# How to run binary at Linux start-up with sound?

Tags: linux, audio, startup, c++, autostart

I have a C++ program where I use the SDL2_Mixer module (which is based on Pulsesink, I think) to output audio. I want to run it on startup, but it does not want to work out very well. I set my default audio output device, volume etc. at startup automatically and have tried different ways to run the binary.

First, I included it in the Linux startup applications app. Then, I created a script in /etc/init.d which should run the binary and gave execute permissions. In both ways, I didn't hear any sound, even after I programmed in a delay so it can be made sure that everything is loaded and set when the binary runs.

Here's my code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL_mixer.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

const char waveFileName[40] = "audio/startup_sound.wav";
Mix_Chunk* sample;

int main() {
    if (Mix_Init(MIX_INIT_FLAC | MIX_INIT_MP3 | MIX_INIT_OGG) < 0) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    memset(sample, 0, sizeof(Mix_Chunk*) * 2);
    if (Mix_OpenAudio(44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 1024) < 0) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    Mix_AllocateChannels(2);
    sample = Mix_LoadWAV(waveFileName);
    if (sample == NULL) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    Mix_Volume(0, MIX_MAX_VOLUME);
    Mix_PlayChannel(0, sample, 0);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(13));

    Mix_FreeChunk(sample);
    Mix_CloseAudio();
    Mix_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I want to point out that when I run the program manually from the terminal, it works perfectly. Is there a way to execute it automatically on startup so the audio output works?
Thanks!

Comment: Does it work when you manually run it as root? I'd suggest systemd an execute as user.

Comment: @Fiximan As I said in the post, when I run it manually (root or without root), it works just as intended. Can you please specify what you mean by "systemd an execute as user"?

Comment: By "sytemd an[d] execute as user" I thought about making it a systemd service with `after=graphical.target` and put it in the user's systemd directory.